# The cell in jsGrid had not being updated

Tags: javascript, jsgrid

i am working on lightswitch project ,and I am using `JsGrid`.I ran into one problem and I don't couldn't find the solution.
here is the scenario:
I use the grid to get data from database table,when I update one of the cell It's value doesn't appear unless I click on the cell again,and if I update it in the second time then the new value appear.
I tried to refresh the grid after itemupdated but still the new value doesn't appear instantaneously.
my code is here:

```
$("#jsGrid").jsGrid({
        width: "100%",
        height: "auto",
           inserting: true,
        editing: true,
        sorting: true,
        paging: true,
        autoload: true,
        controller: {
            loadData: function () {
                var deferred = jQuery.Deferred();
                myapp.activeDataWorkspace.ApplicationData.Table1Items.load().done(function (data) {
                    deferred.resolve(data.results);
                });
                return deferred.promise();
            },
            updateData: function () {
                $("#jsGrid").jsGrid("refresh");
            },
            deleteItem: function (Item) {
                $("#jsGrid").jsGrid("refresh");
            }
        },
        fields: [
            { name: "EmployeeName", type: "text", width: 150 },

            { name: "Points", type: "text", width: 200 },

            { type: "control", editButton: true,                               // show edit button
                deleteButton: true,                             // show delete button
                clearFilterButton: true,                        // show clear filter button
                modeSwitchButton: true                     // show switching filtering/inserting button


            }]
        ,
        onItemInserted: function (item) {

        }, onItemUpdating: function (item) {


          $("#jsGrid").jsGrid("refresh");
        },
        onItemUpdated: function (item)     

            {
            $("#jsGrid").jsGrid("refresh");
            console.log("it is updated", item.item);
            $("#jsGrid").jsGrid("refresh");

        }
    });
```

your help is invaluable and many thanks in advance.

Comment: welcome to stack overflow, see [how to format code](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)

Comment: so you see empty row after updates, or only particular cells are not displayed? Could you try to reproduce the issue forking this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/tabalinas/cy8b8Lro/ or just provide a public link to see the problem?

Comment: Thank you for your response,I used it but still I had the same problem "I have to click on update two times to update the value in the cell"

Answer (score 0):

hope this may help you. 
`updateItem` is a function returning updated item or jQuery promise that will be resolved with updated item. Accepts updating item object.
on successful updating Item, use

```
updateItem: function(item) {
    return $.ajax({
        type: "PUT",
        url: "/items",
        data: item
    });
},
```

[image]
if you have any queries, comment below.
fore more details : see [link](https://github.com/tabalinas/jsgrid)